# AWS Cognito login 'code' vs 'token' response type (# symbol in redirect URL)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to learn how to use AWS Cognito, and I'm confused about the different 'response_type' options when integrating my (test) client app with the Cognito login UI. If I select 'token' rather than 'code', the redirect URL generated by Cognito following successful login has a '#' symbol before the arguments, which prevents my test app (python, Flask) from parsing the arguments.

I'm wondering if someone can explain the intended use cases for these two methods?

So far I have...

- Created a user pool and added a user in AWS Management Console
- Under the 'App Client Settings' set my sign in callback URL to https://localhost/test/
- Created a basic python app with flask for testing the callbacks
- Configured gunicorn to run my flask app with ssl certificate, so my app works with https requests

The code for my Flask test app is as follows...

```
import os
import traceback

from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test/', methods=['GET'])
def test():

  try:  
    resp = jsonify(request.args)
    status = 200

  except:
    resp = traceback.format_exc()
    status = 500

  return resp, status

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.debug = True
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 80)))
```

If I enter the following URL into chrome, with the 'code' response type, my app seems to work as expected

Login Url...

https://[domain].auth.[region].amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=[id]&redirect_uri=https://localhost/test/

Redirect URL...

https://localhost/test/?code=[code]

Test app json...

```
{
  code: [code]
}
```

However, if I enter the following, with the 'token' response type, the redirect url is generated with a '#' symbol before the arguments, and my Flask app doesn't see any of them.

Login Url...

https://[domain].auth.[region].amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=[id]&redirect_uri=https://localhost/test/

Redirect URL...

https://localhost/test/#id_token=[token]&access_token[access_token]=&expires_in=3600&token_type=Bearer

Test app json...

```
{}
```

Note that the behaviour that I'm seeing does correspond with Amazon's documentation of the response format, I just don't understand why it is the way it is.

Comment: find any solution?